# How to use bootstrap to create portfolio grids with 2 column and each item different height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

```html
<!-- PORTFOLIO SECTION -->
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="col-1" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/960x960" class="img-responsive img-case" alt="Responsive image" alt width="100%">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="col-2" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/960x700" class="img-responsive img-case" alt="Responsive image" alt width="100%">
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END First row, left column with 2 items nested -->
        <!-- START First row, right column with 2 items nested -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="col-3" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/960x700.png" class="img-responsive img-case" alt="Responsive image" alt width="100%">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="col-4" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/960x960" class="img-responsive img-case" alt="Responsive image" alt width="100%">
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm trying to create a portfolio grid view with 8 items only inside and sit in two columns divided the screen. Each item has different height. Since it only has 8 items, I think Masonry is too complicated and heavy for beginner like me. I use bootstrap and css coded like the embeded code here. In this dummy way, it can reach two columns divided the screen and 4 items in each column for desktop version.

However, when it goes to mobile version, the stacking sequence is like below illustration shows[mobile stacking sequence illustrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrhPp.jpg). I marked the sequence I'd like to achieve in the illustration.

Can anyone give me advice on how to achieve that? I'm also open to the feedback if you think Masonry is easier to achieve that, please do let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Just added the code. However, since I'm using bootstrap and I don't know how to put bootstrap folder in snipper. So, the rendering is different from what it supposed to be.